# How can I get 2 digits in a time that I get from mySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I am using this code for get only the time from a timestamp in mySQL with PHP.

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row['timestampSQL']);
$time = date('G:i:s', $timestamp);
```

and this shows 3:00, would be so difficult to show 03:00?

Thanks again, Leandro.

Comment: any particular reason?

Comment: this is also a typo btw.

Comment: More of an RTM than a typo, IMO.

Comment: Anything to do with MySQL here ?

Comment: there should be a RTM flag (as alternative to a dupe) with a link to the corresponding manual

Comment: Best of both worlds @PatrickQ ;-)

Comment: Btw, why store time as a string? MySQL has built-in functions made for this and makes for querying a lot easier.... IMO.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner there was for sure a discussion on meta already about introducing a RTM flag, right? (a short search didn't give me something matching)

Comment: `$time = date('G:i:s', $timestamp); $time = "0". $time;` - *heh!* Ok so it's a hack :p

Comment: @PatrickQ What does RTM stand for?

Comment: @Jeff I didn't `R`ead `T`he `M`emo ;-) TBH, I'm not much of a meta'er.

Comment: Maybe this ^ ? @GrumpyCrouton :-))

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton A more polite version of [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks :)

Comment: @PatrickQ Oh, the `F`ull `M`emo, right? me neither.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I did a quick google search for "RTM" before posting my comment, and found nothing that I thought could be related. I found "Release to me", "release to manufacturer", etc.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I got this back from the "Goo" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTM - take your pick? :-))

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner That's interesting, Wikipedia doesn't even show up on the first page of results for me

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton RTFM is the typical usage, but would surely get your comment flagged these days.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yeah, funny how comments with that "R....M" gets flagged but new meta questions not. I don't get that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS you can see in the docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> G 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 0 through 23
>
> H 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23

So, replace:

```
$time = date('G:i:s', $timestamp);
```

With

```
$time = date('H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I had already read that page in spanish but I couldn't find it! Obviously worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `G: i: s`

but should use `H: i: s` to convert its time to 0X if the result of H is less than 10

here is an example

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT '2018-10-11 03:48:22' AS now");
$date = $query->row['now'];
$time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($date));
print_r($time);
```

the result is: `03:48:22`